# Creating custom keyboard controls [Elm]

Tags: keyboard, signals, elm

I'm trying to create custom keyboard controls for a 4 player game.  Right now, the keys are predetermined like this:

```
type Orient = { x:Int, y:Int }
type GameInput = { space:Bool, delta:Time, so1:Orient, so2:Orient, so3:Orient, 
                   so4:Orient, amount:Int }


gameInput : Signal GameInput
gameInput = 
             let sampledInput = sampleOn delta 
                                <| GameInput <~ Keyboard.space
                                              ~ delta
                                              ~ Keyboard.arrows
                                              ~ Keyboard.wasd
                                              ~ Keyboard.directions (toCode 'O')
                                                                    (toCode 'L')
                                                                    (toCode 'K')
                                                                    (toCode 'M')
                                              ~ Keyboard.directions (toCode 'Y')
                                                                    (toCode 'H')
                                                                    (toCode 'G')
                                                                    (toCode 'J')
                                              ~ amountPlayers.signal
             in  lift (Debug.watch "input") sampledInput
```

I have created (for each player) input of the form:

```
type CustomKeys = { up:Char, down:Char, left:Char, right:Char }

customKeys2 : Signal CustomKeys
customKeys2 = CustomKeys <~ ck2up.signal 
                          ~ ck2down.signal 
                          ~ ck2left.signal 
                          ~ ck2right.signal

ck2up : Input Char
ck2up = input 'W'

ck2down : Input Char
ck2down = input 'S'

ck2left : Input Char
ck2left = input 'A'

ck2right : Input Char
ck2right = input 'D'
```

A handler elsewhere will adjust the values of the input as needed by the player. But I'm having a hard time figuring out how to insert these values into the arguments for `Keyboard.directions`.

I have tried lifting the arguments into `Keyboard.directions` directly:

```
~ Keyboard.directions <~ ...
```

Any result will become a Signal of a Signal, which cannot be lifted onto `GameInput` (correctly).

I have tried passing on the chars as arguments into `gameInput`:

```
gameInput2 : Signal GameInput
gameInput2 = gameInput <~ customKeys2

gameInput : CustomKeys -> Signal GameInput
gameInput { up,down,left,right } = GameInput <~ Keyboard.directions (toCode up)
                                                                    (toCode down)
                                                                    (toCode left)
                                                                    (toCode right)
```

Now `gameInput2` will have as result a signal of a signal.

My last idea is to combine signals, but that doesn't seem like an option to me since I want one signal to depend on another signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly using `Keyboard.directions` is not gonna work. The problem is that at the start of the game the keys can be changed so you have some `Signal Char`. And `Keyboard.direction` goes from "normal types" to "signal types". So you can't lift it.

But you also have access to the keys that are currently held down, `Keyboard.keysDown`. I looked up the [implementation of `Keyboard.directions`](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/master/src/Native/Keyboard.js#L116-132) and I think you can recreate it in Elm in a way that has it take `Signal Int` arguments.

Here's an Elm implementation of the normal `Keyboard.directions`:

```
directions : Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Signal { x : Int, y : Int }
directions up down left right = 
  (\kd -> 
    List.filter (\ky -> List.member ky [up,down,left,right]) kd |>
      List.foldl (\ky st -> if | ky == up    -> { st | y <- st.y + 1 }
                               | ky == down  -> { st | y <- st.y - 1 }
                               | ky == left  -> { st | x <- st.x - 1 }
                               | ky == right -> { st | x <- st.x + 1 }
      ) {x=0,y=0}
  ) <~ Keyboard.keysDown
```

and here's the implementation you'll want to use:

```
directions : Signal Int -> Signal Int -> Signal Int -> Signal Int -> Signal { x : Int, y : Int }
directions up down left right = 
  (\u d l r kd -> 
    List.filter (\ky -> List.member ky [u,d,l,r]) kd |>
      List.foldl (\ky st -> if | ky == u -> { st | y <- st.y + 1 }
                               | ky == d -> { st | y <- st.y - 1 }
                               | ky == l -> { st | x <- st.x - 1 }
                               | ky == r -> { st | x <- st.x + 1 }
      ) {x=0,y=0}
  ) <~ up ~ down ~ left ~ right ~ Keyboard.keysDown
```

Feel free to refactor, I just hacked this code together quickly so it's kind of too large for a single function.