# Configurable inputs in model (Elm 0.13)

Tags: keyboard, signals, elm

For an Elm (0.13) game I'm developing, I'd like to have reconfigurable inputs. A simplified version of the model that I've got for this is

```
type Controls = {
    up:    KeyCode,
    down:  KeyCode,
    left:  KeyCode,
    right: KeyCode
}

type Player = {
    ...
    controls: Controls,
    ...
}

type Game = {
    state: State,
    players: [Player]
}
```

For the game loop, I'm using a standard `foldp` construction, where I'd like the input to be dependent of the current state of the game. So far I tried the following:

```
gameState =
    let 
        initialGame = (newGame initialActive)
    in
        foldp update initialGame (input initialGame)
```

but of course, the input signal generating function (`input : Game -> Signal Input`) keeps on using the initial game, and not the changed gamestate.

I've searched troughout the internet to find a solution to this, but I couldn't find anything in this direction. Is there a way to do it the way I was trying (by including the controls in the model), or will I have to release the controls from the model by making the controls signals themselves?

Comment: Minor note: the capitalisation of the programming language is elm or Elm. IIRC this was discussed on the mailing list, but I can't find the source at this time.

Comment: @Apanatshka However the question was solved, I'll update it anyway ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a closely related question here: [Creating custom keyboard controls [Elm]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27512004/859279)

If you want to, you can keep the `Controls` part of your game state. The way to do this is not to base your input on the `initialGame`, but to take more general input from which you can always extract what you need. In this case that would be `Keyboard.keysDown`. Then you can get the input for each player using:

```hs
playerInput : Controls -> [KeyCode] -> { x : Int, y : Int }
playerInput {up,down,left,right} kd = 
  List.filter (\ky -> List.member ky [up,down,left,right]) kd |>
    List.foldl (\ky st -> if | ky == up    -> { st | y <- st.y + 1 }
                             | ky == down  -> { st | y <- st.y - 1 }
                             | ky == left  -> { st | x <- st.x - 1 }
                             | ky == right -> { st | x <- st.x + 1 }
    ) {x=0,y=0}
```

If you want to remove `Controls` from `Game` you can hoist it up into the definition of the input for the `foldp`.

Comment: I had found the related question, but maybe there was a way to loop the result of `foldl` back into `input`. I tried it, as you described, by gathering all keyboard input and checking for the correct signals afterwards and this indeed works! I'm happy I can keep this in my model, as I intended it to be, thanks!